# Using mysql JSON_SEARCH: Why do I have to quote numbers?

Tags: mysql, json

I have a "test" table with a PK field "id" and a JSON field "json_data". I make the following insert:

```
insert into test (json_data) values (JSON_ARRAY(1,2));
```

However, if I do

```
select * from test where JSON_SEARCH(json_data, 'all', 2) is not null;
```

I get "Empty set". Although if I insert

```
insert into test (json_data) values (JSON_ARRAY("1","2"));
```

and then repeat the query, I indeed finally get

```
+----+------------+
| id | json_data  |
+----+------------+
|  2 | ["1", "2"] |
+----+------------+
```

Why do I have to quote the numbers in order to be able to query on them? I'd rather not do that, is there a way around?

Comment: [JSON_SEARCH function works with only string scalars as mentioned in the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52992287/2794280)

Answer (score 0):

JSON_SEARCH only works with strings, per the MySQL documentation.

try this:

```
SET @j = '[3, 2, 1]';
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(@j, '3', '$');
```