# How do I use JSON_SEARCH() to find the path of a number in a MySQL JSON array?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

*Note*: This is for MySQL 5.7.

When I attempt to use `JSON_SEARCH` to find the path to a number value within a JSON array, I get `NULL`. But when I use `JSON_SEARCH` to look for a string, I actually get the path.

```sql
# String Search Example

SET @json = '[1, 2, 3, "abc"]';
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(@json, 'one', 'abc');

----------
| "$[3]" |
----------
```

...but when I explicitly search for a number value, I get `NULL`?

```sql
# Number Search Example

SET @json = '[1, 2, 3, "abc"]';
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(@json, 'one', 1);

----------
| NULL   |
----------
```

What's strange is that `JSON_CONTAINS` still works as intended with numbers or strings.

---

This may be similar to this question -> [MYSQL Triggers: JSON_SEARCH an integer value in a json array of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356672/mysql-triggers-json-search-an-integer-value-in-a-json-array-of-integers)

Answer (score 2):

**JSON_SEARCH** function works with only string scalars as mentioned in the documentation : [Functions That Search JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html)

Here you can see:

Reported bug - [JSON_SEARCH does not search for non-string values](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79233)

Reported feature - [Make JSON_SEARCH work for non-strings](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90085)